# JasperReport: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression :

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am generating a jasper report with Java.
It has a Student bean which contains college_name and a list of student_info(second bean).
Student_info contains student_Name and address.
I have set college_Name and the list of Student_info bean to Student bean.

I am getting values when I set only the student_info(second bean) object (not List) to Student bean, but getting an error invalid expression when I pass the list of Student_info bean.
I do not know how to get Student_info list and then its value like student_Name and address.

It gives me the following error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
aa DEBUG net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.DeduplicableRegistry: Found existing instance net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRTemplateText@526b3f for object net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRTemplateText@2b5c2d
Source text : $F{Student_infoDTOList}.getName()
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:244)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:591)
aa DEBUG net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.DeduplicableRegistry: Added object net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRTemplateText@b0c9f0
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:559)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:1016)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:504)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:488)
aa DEBUG net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField: created net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRTemplateText@b0c9f0 for (null, null)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:456)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2057)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:778)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:288)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:932)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:864)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:114)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969)
```

My JRXml file is:

```
<textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
            <reportElement key="textField" x="42" y="0" width="112" height="13" uuid="1e3a7dff-583c-4322-88cb-c2c0f1ea7569"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="10"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Student_infoDTOList}.getName()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Comment: post your jrxml file for more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow this step.

- Define text field in detail band.
- Add a new field with name of attribute of object from list. e.g. student_name, address.
- right click on text field and click on edit expression. set field name as student_name.
- Now run your application.

Comment: i already tried this but it gives me error,when i provide the student_name as a field name that time it cant read the Inner Bean and  gives error can't read value from outer bean as Student_name is a attribute of Inner Bean then please tell me how i read the value of Inner bean